# intel-microcode 20180108 not in app center?

Tags: appcenter

the app center is still showing intel-microcode 20170707
When can we get intel-microcode 20180108 ?(for the spectre bug fix?)

Also when will elementary os update the kernel for the meltdown fix? still have kernel 4.10 without kpti

grz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I got it.

```
» lsb_release -a                               
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki
Release:        0.4.1
Codename:       loki
» apt show intel-microcode | grep Version

Version: 3.20180108.0~ubuntu16.04.2
```

as of kernel. I personally have

```
» uname -a                                                                                                  127 ↵
Linux darkstar 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(fresh install) as per `apt search linux-image` I see plenty of kernels there, I should be able to install something appropriate

Comment: Tnx for the info got it to now ^^